# UseContentRoot not using values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on a project which use the Kestrel Webserver and runs as a service. I've followed [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on how to create such a service. Basically everything is fine if I start the project from the command line.

The issue arises when it is started as a service from the services.msc panel or via the sc start command. I added some logging to see what is actually happening.

The following calls are in place (in the same way as in the example):

```
pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(webHostArgs)
    .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
    .UseNLog()
    .Build();
```

From the logging, I can see that the pathToContentRoot is what I expect (also there I can find the appsettings.json file)

Yet, as soon as I open the webpage, I get the following error message in the log:

> 2018-06-27
>   13:47:55.8391|1|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware|An
>   unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file
>   'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical
>   path is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\appsettings.json'.
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean
>   reload)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1
>   providers)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>          at GrafWebsearch.Services.EmailSender..ctor() in A:\engineering\InterneTools\GrafWebsearch\GrafWebsearch\Services\EmailSender.cs:line
>   20
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCreateInstance(CreateInstanceCallSite
>   createInstanceCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)

This clearly indicates that it looks for the appconfig.json at the usual directory in which windows services are run and not in the directory specified with UseContentRoot.

I should mention that I upgrated from .NET core 1.1 to 2.1 - maybe there was some change there?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

At some completely different part of my code (EmailSender.cs) I didn't correctly inject the Configuration, instead I created a new one, including the lines

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
```

It looks like this cause my application to overwrite the actual configuration. Once I had the injection through the constructor corrected, everything worked.